# jQuery .not(), multiple excludes with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I got this small piece of code to reset a form:

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $(':input','#fundingpossibility')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('');
});
```

I'd like to add an input field with, let's say, an id of `#test` to the `.not()` selector. I've tried various things, but can't make it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just add another comma ([multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)), for example:

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $(':input','#fundingpossibility')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, #test')
  .val('');
});
```

Comment: @Alex - you have something outside the question going on then, this is pretty clear-cut on how it's done, do you have the markup to look at?

Comment: My wrong man, had the button type="reset". That messed up the whole thing. It works as you suggested. Probably need some sleep. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Is the input field #test within the #fundingpossibility id or not?