# Use the "not" in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this line and this code, it works :
**not([href^="mailto:"])**, so I excluded the links with the "mailto", and know I want to exclude a link with a specific ID. How can I do ?

```
$(function() {
    var speed = 'slow'; 

    $(".loader").fadeOut(speed, function() {
        $('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            if (url.indexOf('#') !== 0 && url.indexOf('javascript:') !== 0) {

                $(".loader").fadeIn(speed, function() {
                    window.location = url;
                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545211/jquery-not-multiple-excludes-with-id ?

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5684160/218196

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])').not("#yourIdHere" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

```
$('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"]):not(#the-id-to-exclude)')...
```

Or:

```
$('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"])').not('#the-id-to-exclude')....
```

Comment: `:not("#the-id-to-exclude")` should be `:not(#the-id-to-exclude)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href]:not([href^="mailto:"]):not(#your_ID)').on('click', function(event) {
```

This should do the Job.

Comment: `:not("#your_ID")` should be `:not(#your_ID)`.