# make accordion for specific ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I want to create accordion for some specific blocks with ID.

1 when i click on some *li >  a href=#**ID*** 
2 all child in div#content with specified IDs are closing 
3 show *div#content div#**ID***

content:

```
    <div id='body'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='home'>
            some for home blocks
            content
            </div>
            <div id='news'>
            some for news blocks
            content
            </div>
            <div id='sub_news'>
            some for sub news blocks
            content that will always displayed
            </div>
            <div id='work'>
            some for work blocks
            content
            </div>
            <div id='contacts'>
            some for contacts blocks
            content
            </div>
            <div id='contacts2'>
            some for contacts2 blocks
            content that will display too
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

navigation:

```
        <ul id='navigation_1'>
            <li id='li_1_home' class='nav_current_li_1 first'><a class='replace' href='#home' id='navigation_1_news' title='link to gome'>go home<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li id='li_1_news'><a class='replace' href='#news' id='navigation_1_news' title='news'>news<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li id='li_1_work'><a class='replace' href='#work' id='navigation_1_raboty' title='some work'>some work<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li id='li_1_some'><a class='replace' href='http://google.com' id='navigation_1_link' title='some link'>some link<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='last' id='li_1_contact'><a class='replace' href='#contacts' id='navigation_1_contact' title='some contacts'>Contacts<span></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

i don't need a function for every a href and divs
and i need only specific IDs, not everylink in #navigation_1 > li a !

i think mb need some database with div#id that will be toggled to

Comment: where Nenad Vracar answer https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/920/ ? tooclose but thx i'll try testing by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tempory worked, thx from [jQuery .not(), multiple excludes with id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545211/jquery-not-multiple-excludes-with-id)

```
$('#navigation_1 li a').click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); //for move to anchors
  $( $(this).attr('href') ).slideToggle('slow'); //Expand or collapse this blocks
  $("#content > div").not( $(this).attr('href')', #sub_news, #contacts, #contacts2').slideUp('fast'); //Hide the other blocks
})
```